# Is it possible to remove some part of HTML from source for mobile using Javascript or any server side technique?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mobile-website

Is it possible to remove **(** not hide using `display:none` **)** some part of HTML from source for mobile using Javascript or any server side technique?

**For example** suppose below is the code inside `<body>` of one of the page of website

For example this is page for **desktop Browsers**.

```
<header class="hd1">

        <hgroup>
        <h1>A Responsive page</h1>
        </header>

    <div class="main">

        <section class="hs1">

            <header>
            <h1>This is a Page Sub Title</h1>
            </header>

            <p>Some content...</p>

            <h2>Demonstrating EM and STRONG</h2>

            <p>This text will have more importance></p>


        </section><!-- .hs1 -->

        </div><!-- .main -->

    <aside class="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </aside>

    <footer class="f1">
    <p>copyright &copy; year</p>
    </footer>
```

And using **same page for Mobile devices** I only want to remove `<aside>...</aside>` from the source.

I can't use different page because is CMS based. By updating content once I want to show on all devices. But in mobile version of Website I just want to remove (hide) some things from source. because If i will just use `display:none` mobile will load same amount of data of desktop version which is not for performance on mobile. 
Can we remove some specific part of source for mobile using Javascript or server side technique?

**Edit after some responses**

As many user commented that JavaScript cannot be used to reduce the payload to mobile users. So what could be the server side solution to deliver the same page but remove some part of it from source before delivering it?

Comment: JavaScript (if you mean client-side) is not an option for this since it does not affect what is sent to the device.

Comment: What you are looking for is essentially `User-Agent:` sniffing, which is not a good thing to do because it is very hard to keep on top of the constantly changing list. However, if you really *must* do it, [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) would be the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can [detect mobile browser](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php) on the server and just not render this tag.

There's no point in removing this using javascript, if you do this to save bandwidth.

Comment: If the OP is looking to reduce the HTML payload, why bother suggesting client-size ways of hiding it?

Comment: @Sergei - I just given an example of one tag but in actually it could be any tag and tag with classed or IDs.

Comment: @JitendraVyas yeah, so? Check for mobile browser in those places and don't render those tags. You may want to move browser detection to the beginning of page rendering process and not duplicate it every time. Maybe your CMS even does this for you (and provides some pre-set flag, like `$is_mobile_browser`).

Answer (score 0):

Sure this can be done server-side. You can solve this in two ways (*script* in the following means a script on the server-side, not in the browser):

- The script builds the HTML and only output according to the target platform.
- The script outputs the HTML and a filter / post-process changes that output according to the target platform.

One technique for that in the area of HTML/XHTML are *XSL Transformations*. You can run those with PHP, [support for XSL is available in a PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xsl.php).

Naturally you can do this manually as well with string operations or `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`.

To post-process the standard output, you can do so by implementing an [output handler/callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you but there is an alternative solution. It is not straightforward, but it is interesting :).

1. Return by default only "lightweight" version of the page.
2. Detect using JavaScript if we are on low bandwidth connection.
3. If we are not on slow conection then load the rest using AJAX.

Modernizr introduced a feature test for detecting slow connection (see **[this](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/network-connection.js)**) :

```
var connection = navigator.connection || { type: 0 }; // polyfill

return connection.type == 3 // connection.CELL_2G 
  || connection.type == 4   // connection.CELL_3G
  || /^[23]g$/.test(connection.type); // string value in new spec
```

The problem - it seems that this is not supported that well in current browsers.

After using this connection test (and maybe UA sniffing as a backup) you can load the rest of the page using [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

Well with asp.net you can set div or any HTML element to run on server side then hide or display programatically  according to device. You can use some device and capability defection  framework to decide.

I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard with PHP etc too